# Can I use the same map key several times?

Tags: javascript

I'm storing and retrieving data like this:

```
data = new Map();
data.set("key", id);
data.set("key", id2);
data.get("key");
```

the second set is overwriting key element.
I want a structure, that can hold multiple times the key element or one key element with multiple id data pairs. Does such a collection exist in Javascript or how to achieve this?

thank you

Comment: No, keys must be unique. You'd have to use an array of objects or something else. It would be helpful if we had more context to offer suggestions.

Comment: not natively, you'd have to write the logic for that

Comment: If you want to have more then one value for a key, an array or set holding those values as value for that key would make perfect sense.

Comment: Example: `data.set("key", [id, id2])`

Comment: also note that a map makes most sense when your keys are not just strings. If you have only string values as keys, you can use an object, if not, you have to use a map because object can only have string keys while a map can have anything as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and no other JS structure I'm aware of allows you to have more occurences of the same key. Keys must be unique.

I think that maybe unshifting new values into an array stored in a regular object might be a good way to achieve what you want. That way, your newest value will always be the first in the array, and thus accessible at index 0, like so:

```
const data = {key: []};

data.key.unshift(id);
data.key[0] // value of id

data.key.unshift(id2);
data.key[0] // value of id2
```

Comment: Object cannot have duplicate keys either. Your suggestion reads wrong.

Comment: I edited the wording and hopefully cleared the confusion

Comment: and how do i get all elements of the key?

Comment: you can access the whole array like so: `data.key`